# How can we create 2 blocks left and right and with text wrap with css?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is it possible for us to make design exactly like this ?? the red one.

[image]

> Note: The main problem is we did not swipe **HTML** code just play with **CSS**.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible with CSS.

Comment: if the hello block have fixed dimension, it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```css
main {
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flow-root;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.a {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.b::before {
  content: 'Hello';
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.b {
  color: #fff;
}

.c {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="a">Hello</div>
  <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolorum expedita, saepe quam, deleniti dolorem nesciunt pariatur accusantium quas et nam laudantium veritatis alias! Quis maiores nisi nulla necessitatibus dolorem.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolorum expedita, saepe quam, deleniti dolorem nesciunt pariatur accusantium quas et nam laudantium veritatis alias! Quis maiores nisi nulla necessitatibus dolorem.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolorum expedita, saepe quam, deleniti dolorem nesciunt pariatur accusantium quas et nam laudantium veritatis alias! Quis maiores nisi nulla necessitatibus dolorem.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolorum expedita, saepe quam, deleniti dolorem nesciunt pariatur accusantium quas et nam laudantium veritatis alias! Quis maiores nisi nulla necessitatibus dolorem.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolorum expedita, saepe quam, deleniti dolorem nesciunt pariatur accusantium quas et nam laudantium veritatis alias! Quis maiores nisi nulla necessitatibus dolorem.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dolorum expedita, saepe quam, deleniti dolorem nesciunt pariatur accusantium quas et nam laudantium veritatis alias! Quis maiores nisi nulla necessitatibus dolorem.</div>
  <div class="c">hello</div>
</main>
```

Comment: shape-outside are not really needed here, they are doing nothing. You can remove them

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: plum;
}

.a, .c {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
}

.a { float: left; }
.c { float: right; }
```

You can use `margin` and `shape-outside` properties on "floated" boxes to have more control over the wrapped content.